# Inconsistency between Android and JavaScript Parse API

Tags: javascript, android, json, ionic2, parse-server

I'm using **Parse Server** as a back end (the open source version). I have an Android application that saves an object to the server's DB. The object is simply a key-value pair. When the Android application creates an object, it creates it as JSON object.

Now I want to retrieve the same object from an **Ionic 2** app. In Ionic, I use the JS Parse API to access the back end. When an object is created in the JS API, it's created as a plain text object.

As a result I'm getting: `101 Object not found`

It seems like what I need to do is to translate Parse plain text object to Parse JSON object.

This is what I tried to do:

1. According to the JS Parse documentation one of the methods of Parse.Object is toJSON(). I tried to apply this method in different combinations to the Parse object before creating query, but I always get an error:  `this.parse.Object.extend(...).toJSON is not a function`
2. I tried to apply standard JSON Api (i.e. JSON.stringify) to the Parse object. In this case I'm getting an error: `ParseQuery must be constructed with a ParseObject or class name`.
3. I did very extensive search on internet and found nothing helpful.

Would appreciate any ideas on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was corrupted disk on the server side. Created new server and new DB and everything works fine now.